# Понятно ли Вам что-нибудь из следующего кода?

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

```
using std::string;
using std::wstring;
using std::ofstream;

HWND *handlesArray = reinterpret_cast<HWND*>(lpParam);
HWND hProgressBar = handlesArray[0];
SendMessageW(hProgressBar, SBM_SETPOS, 50, 0); 
DWORD code = GetLastError();

map_v values_vector;
try{
    ofstream input("C:\\Data\\IlluminatiInsertQueries_article_price_dimesions.sql");
    //getLustraLux();
    ParseCSV("C:\\Data\\illuminati.csv",values_vector, '|');
    /*
    article, color, lamps, matherial
    */
    map_uv items = getRsd();

    for(auto unicode_item: items) {
        param_map temp;
        for(auto t : unicode_item) {
            temp[ConvertStringToMultibyte(t.first)] = ConvertStringToMultibyte(t.second);
        }
        isValidCheck(temp);


    std::map<wstring, wstring> wmap;
    for(auto map_val: unicode_item) {
        wmap[map_val.first] = map_val.second;
    }

    wstring str_temp = DoQueries(wmap, L"insert", L"catalog", L"");
    std::string mb_str = ConvertStringToMultibyte(str_temp);
    input << mb_str << std::endl;

    }
    throw std::logic_error("Application finished it's work!");

}
catch(const std::exception& ex)
{
    //MessageBoxA(NULL, , " ", NULL);
    MessageBoxA(NULL, ex.what(), "Exception while program work", MB_ICONERROR);
}
return 0;
```

Дополню вопрос:

1. Что мне нужно от Вас: понимаете ли Вы что происходит в этом коде, как оцениваете стиль (плохо\кошмарно\отвратительно\ужасно\лучшее что вы видели в жизни), что бы вы подправили? Ясна ли вообще логика работы функции, или все в тумане?
2. Код написал я сам и сам не могу в нем разобраться. Спрашиваю помощи со стороны, ибо нужен свежий взгляд.

Comment: понятно

Comment: подправил вопрос.

Comment: Автор, пишите комментарии. 


Только не **что** делаете для каждой строчки, а **с какой целью** написан фрагмент кода. 

Укажите форматы данных (вход, выход). Опишите словами, что и в какой кодировке в какой map лежит.

isValidCheck() видимо бросает исключение? Так напишите об этом, а также где оно должно отлавливаться.

     throw std::logic_error("Application finished it's work!");

а этот шедевр какую цель преследует?

Опишите аргументы DoQueries() и что она делает,  укажите **почему** она в отличие от isValidCheck() не может работать с Multibyte.

--

Имхо плохо.

Comment: Хардкод строковых констант (например, "C:\\Data\\illuminati.csv") это  плохо. Очень плохо.

Comment: Если кратко то здесь все намешано в кучу и при этом неочевидна конечная цель всего куска(Отправка SQL запроса? Парс CSV? Конвертация в мультибайт? Работа с окнами? Какая-то проверка хэш таблиц? Исключения которые никогда не произойдут из-за строковой константы с именами файлов?). 
По сути это не метод класса, а просто какая-то свалка которой зачем-то приписали отдельный заголовок-объявление(которого почему-то здесь нет). 

Причин по которому это код плох больше чем самого кода. 

P.S. Не понимаю почему ключом хэш таблицы в обоих случая является строка а не какой-то быстрый хэш от нее?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*IMHO, на [Говнокод](http://govnokod.ru).*

- Смешана модель данных и `view`. Почему в пределах одного метода выполняются какие-то запросы вкупе с показом мессаджбоксов и установкой значения прогрессбара?
- Использование `exception'`ов для `flow control`. Исключения — для **исключительных** ситуаций, особенно в случае `std::logic_error`.
- Безумная связность метода:

  - Сколько измененений придется сделать в приложении, если пользователь захочет выбирать произвольный `csv` файл со входящими данными?
  - А если я захочу записывать результат выполнения не в файл, а дампить его в `JSON` и слать на удаленный сервер?
- Какие-то невнятные тайпдефы типа `map_uv,` методы с названиями `getRsd` и странная логика по преобразованиям строк. Разве нельзя ввести для `rsd` отдельную сущность и сделать какие-нибудь прокси поверх этой сущности, которые будут отвечать за строчные преобразования?
- Не слишком очевидно, как работает `DoQueries` в плане асинхронности. Не знаю, можно ли решить этот вопрос на уровне предложенной функции, но использование терминологии типа `Future,` на мой взгляд, *сильно упростило бы ситуацию.*
- Использование `auto` в и без того неочевидном коде, на мой взгляд, является верхом снобизма. И кстати, да, `map_v values_vector` — это тоже супер-концептуально :)

Comment: Спасибо за govnokod.ru, отличный ресурс!

Comment: Даже там заминусуют это, местные жители любят велосипеды с gamedev или изощренные конструкции из нового стандарта вроде такой int main(){(([](){})());}